# Locating Cookiecutter Extensions

Tags: python, jinja2, cookiecutter

I'm working on creating my first [cookiecutter](http://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). By and large, this has gone well, but I now want to add a jinja2 filter of my own.

In line with the comments [in this issue](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter/issues/547), I've created a new Jinja2 extension [much like the one here](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter/issues/547#issuecomment-196588267). **Full code for this extension is here:**

**https://github.com/seclinch/sigchiproceedings-cookiecutter/commit/5a314fa7207fa8ab7b4024564cec8bb1e1629cad#diff-f4acf470acf9ef37395ef389c12f8613**

However, the following simple example demonstrates the same error:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from jinja2.ext import Extension


def slug(value):
    return value


class PaperTitleExtension(Extension):
    def __init__(self, environment):
        super(PaperTitleExtension, self).__init__(environment)
        environment.filters['slug'] = slug
```

I've dropped this code into a new `jinja2_extensions` directory and added a simple `__init__.py` as follows:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from paper_title import PaperTitleExtension

__all__ = ['PaperTitleExtension']
```

Based on [this piece of documentation](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/template_extensions.html) I've also added the following to my `cookiecutter.json' file:

```
"_extensions": ["jinja2_extensions.PaperTitleExtension"]
```

However, running this generates the following error:

```
$ cookiecutter sigchiproceedings-cookiecutter
Unable to load extension: No module named 'jinja2_extensions'
```

I'm guessing that I'm missing some step here, can anyone help?

Comment: Hey @saff did you ever find the issue?

Comment: @ex0b1t - No, sadly not.

Comment: @Staff I ended up migrating to https://saojs.org/ works way better IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, try executing with python3 -m option

My extension in extensions/json_loads.py

```
import json

from jinja2.ext import Extension


def json_loads(value):
    return json.loads(value)


class JsonLoadsExtension(Extension):
    def __init__(self, environment):
        super(JsonLoadsExtension, self).__init__(environment)
        environment.filters['json_loads'] = json_loads
```

cookiecutter.json

```
{
  "service_name": "test",
  "service_slug": "{{ cookiecutter.service_name.replace('-', '_') }}",
...
  "_extensions": ["extensions.json_loads.JsonLoadsExtension"]
}
```

Then I executed with `python3 -m cookiecutter . no_input=True timestamp="123" extra_dict="{\"features\": [\"redis\", \"grpc_client\"]}" -f` and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar error earlier.

```
Unable to load extension: No module named 'cookiecutter_repo_extensions'
```

The problem was that in my case there was a dependency to the 'cookiecutter-repo-extension' which I had not installed in my Virtual Environment.

Answer (score 0):

The directory containing your extension needs to be on your `PYTHONPATH`.

https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter/issues/1211#issuecomment-522226155

A PR to improve the [docs](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/template_extensions.html) would be appreciated  ✍️